# Splitting Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, small-business, cable

I am looking for the best way to network my small business. I have an office where my router/modem are located, and then 2 more computers in another room. I can route Ethernet to this room with about 75 ft of cabling, and I would like to do this because my computers on Ethernet are getting 3x the speed as computers on wireless.

Is there any way I can use just one Ethernet cable to span the 75 feet, and then  maybe 2 smaller ones to go to the two computers from there? If there's a simple way to do this, maybe with a connector that would be ideal, as opposed to buying over 150 ft of cabling. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called a *switch*.

Comment: Hmm, I've read that an Ethernet switch would only allow internet to one device at a time, we need both computers to be able to use the internet at the same time. Can we do that with a switch?

Comment: This is what you're talking about I assume - http://www.futureshop.ca/en-CA/product/d-link-d-link-5-port-10-100-ethernet-switch-go-sw-5e-go-sw-5e/10263151.aspx?path=178dd5833e1a76514e76354fd617c1d2en02

Comment: @Nathan - yes, but you might as well pay a few dollars more and get one that's Gigabit-capable.

Comment: Item 1: Whatever you've been reading, it's not helping. Read something else instead. Item 2: Yes, that's a switch, and its capacity is likely to be adequate for your purposes, though it is quite a lot cheaper than what we would specify professionally. As @EEAA mentioned, faster/better switches are available.

Comment: @Nathan I don't know what you read, but you definitely misunderstood it. If you got enough switches, you can easily have 100 computers online.

Comment: A gigabit switch is the minimum you should accept these days.